# Learning Curve and time needed to install/manage Centos Server

Tags: untagged

Completely newby question please. I always had shared hosting. Now I am about to get a dedicated Centos server. I now need to know whether I should get a managed one or not. 2 questions please:

1. Whats the learning curve (approx. days/months) assuming I am a fast learner?
2. If I managed it myself, how much of my time (approx. each day) do I need to commit in managing the server? (Assuming normal circumstances).

thank you for any help!

Comment: I don't think we have the faintest chance of answering this question without knowing a lot more about what skillsets you **do** have.  Are you an experienced Windows admin?  An ubuntu admin?  A sushi chef?  Those three people will likely have three wildly different times coming up to speed on CentOS.

Comment: @MadHatter +1 for the sushi chef

Comment: mauro: what can I say?  I was hungry.

Comment: I am a web programmer (PHP, JS). I never handled a server apart from control panels. Does that help to get an approximation of how much time it would take to learn it?

Comment: No sysadmin experience of any kind?  Get a managed server.  Learning the trade on production kit is not a good idea, unless you don't value your business at all.

Comment: This is really "too broad" but I marked it as a duplicate of the above question, which covers the knowledge you will need to be successful here. As you can see, it really is rather broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was in your shoes, I would rent a very cheap VPS (less than $5/month) and have the provider install your intended Centos distrib on it. Use this to determine your comfort level with working with the platform before renting a dedicated server.

Also, please note that the amount of time spent managing a server will vary depending on what is running on the server.